# Trying to refactor a promisified function in to try-catch block

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, try-catch

I am trying to refactor this code using try-catch blocks:

```
export const authorizeConnectyCube = async (accessToken) => {
  const userCredentials = {
    provider: 'firebase_phone',
    'firebase_phone[project_id]': "xxxxxxxx",
    'firebase_phone[access_token]': accessToken,
  };
  await createSession();
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ConnectyCube.login(userCredentials, (error, user) => {
      user ? resolve(user) : reject(error);
    })
  }).catch(error => console.log(error));
}

const createSession = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ConnectyCube.createSession((error, session) => {
      session ? resolve(session.user) : reject(error)
    })
  }).catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

However I'm not getting the same result - the asynchronousity seems to be being handled differently. Here is my attempt at refactoring:

```
export const authorizeConnectyCube = async (accessToken) => {

  const userCredentials = {
    provider: 'firebase_phone',
    'firebase_phone[project_id]': "xxxxxxxxxx",
    'firebase_phone[access_token]': accessToken,
  };

  await createSession();
  try {
    ConnectyCube.login(userCredentials, (error, user) => {
      return user;
    })
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}

const createSession = () => {
  try {
    ConnectyCube.createSession((error, session) => {
      return session.user
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Is there any particular part of what I'm wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Callback-based APIs don't readily turn into something you can use for `async`/`await` (which under the hood uses promises). You'll have to "promisify" them first (i.e. wrap them in promises).

Here's an example of what I'm trying to say:

```
// Promisify these callback-based APIs.
const login = userCredentials => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ConnectyCube.login(userCredentials, (error, user) => {
      user ? resolve(user) : reject(error);
    })
  })
})

const createSession = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ConnectyCube.createSession((error, session) => {
      session ? resolve(session.user) : reject(error)
    })
  })
})

// Then use them in an async function
export const authorizeConnectyCube = async (accessToken) => {
  const userCredentials = {
    provider: 'firebase_phone',
    'firebase_phone[project_id]': "xxxxxxxx",
    'firebase_phone[access_token]': accessToken,
  }

  try {
    await createSession()
    return login(userCredentials)
  } catch (e) {
    console.warn(e)
  } 
}
```

Also, `async` functions return promises, with the resolved value being the return value, and the rejected value being any uncaught error thrown inside. A value wrapped in a promise as return value for an async function is redundant.

If you're using Node 8+, it has a utility called [`promisify`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) which accepts a callback-based API and returns a promise-returning version of it.